# VSCode adds extra indent to closing parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm encountering an issue with VSCode where, when splitting long function calls onto multiple lines, the closing parenthesis gets an extra indentation.

In particular, when I hit enter after the last argument (and before the closing parenthesis), it gets an extra indent. Here's an example:

```
value = myfunction(
    arg1=arg1, 
    arg2=arg2
    )  # extra indent should be removed here
```

On the other hand, if I hit enter before writing input arguments, it goes to the desired location:

```
value = myfunction(        
)
```

The extension called "python indent" did not solve this problem.

Comment: You want it changed for visual reasons, yes? It shouldnt cause any issues

Comment: I think VSCode expects trailing commas. Add a `,` after `arg2=arg2`. VSCode should indent correctly the closing parentheses.

Comment: @thetaco my company wants me to do this way, and I occasionally forget to remove the extra indent.

Answer (score 0):

You could open your settings(shortcuts **ctrl+,**) and search for `editor.autoIndent`. Change it to none, the editor will not insert indentation automatically.

This is the same as add `"editor.autoIndent": "none"` in your `settngs.json`.